# How to find conditional rolling mean in dataframe?

Tags: python, database

I have dataframe as:

```
st      ft  value
10      12       10
9       13       20
8       9        30
7       8        40
6       7        50
5       8        60
4       5        70
3       4        80
2       4        90
1       2       100
```

The code for creating above DataFrame:

df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [12, 13, 9, 8, 7, 8, 5, 4,4,2], 
              [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]).T.rename(columns={0:"st", 1:"ft", 2:"value"})

In the dataFrame there are three column st (which is experiment start time), ft(experiment finish time) and value(Observed value). Finish time >start time. I want to create a new column having the previous observed value. But the condition of taking the last observed value is - 
finish time(last row) <= start time(current row) such that finish time is maximum.

Applying the above logic, the output should look like -

```
st        ft    value   last_observed_value
10        12    10         30.0
9         13    20         30.0
8         9     30         40.0
7         8     40         50.0
6         7     50         70.0
5         8     60         70.0
4         5     70         80.0
3         4     80        100.0
2         4     90        100.0
1         2     100       None
```

How can we do it pythonic way?

Comment: can you explain the condition used for last_observerd_value? please, verify that your expected value table contains the correct value.

Comment: for last_observed_value if the st of current row <= ft of next row , then the last_observed_value should be the value of the next row, correct?

Comment: @paradox you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [12, 13, 9, 8, 7, 8, 5, 4,4,2], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]).T.rename(columns={0:"st", 1:"ft", 2:"value"})
```

---

```
df['last_observed_value'] =  -10000
for i in range(df.st.size - 1):
    for j in range(i,df.st.size - 1):
        if(df.st[j]< df.ft[j+1]):
            df['last_observed_value'][i] =  df.value[j+1]
        if(df.st[j] == df.ft[j+1]):
            df['last_observed_value'][i] =  df.value[j+1]
            break
```

Comment: Can it be possible to write in the form of lamda expression?